# Passing state to react-router 1.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In `react-router` version 0.13.3 I have

```
Router.run(routes, createBrowserHistory, function(Handler, state) {
    React.render(<Handler query={ state } path={ state.pathname }/>, document.getElementById('app'))
});
```

In `react-router` 1.0.0.rc3 I have

```
let history = createBrowserHistory();
React.render(<Router history={ history } >{ routes }</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

With `react-router` 0.13.3, I was able to pass state to my Components with a callback. I was wondering how I can do the same with version `react-router` 1.x ?

Answer (score 3):

React Router 1.0 now creates elements from your route components, passing them the following routing-related state as props by default:

- `history` - a [History](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#history) object
- `location` - a [Location](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/Location.md) object
- `params` - parameters extracted from the URL
- `route` - the route object the rendered component belongs to
- `routeParams` - parameters extracted from the URL for the route object the rendered component belongs to
- `routes` - an array of all the route objects which were matched

You should be able to use these to get a hold of routing-related state, e.g. to get the pathname, you could use `this.props.location.pathname` inside a route component, or pass these onto children which need them.

[The 1.0 upgrade guide has more details about this](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#state-mixin).

---

If you want to pass additional props to an individual route component when rendering it, you can use [`React.cloneElement()`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) like so:

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {extra: 'extra prop'})
```

---

If you want to pass additional props when a route component element is being created, you can [pass a custom `createElement()` function to `<Router>`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#createelementcomponent-props).